# No such table error in Sqlite Database swift 4.2 after change from swift 3

Tags: ios, sqlite.swift, xcode11.4

I'm trying to retrieve a count of records in a table using SQLite.swift and Swift in a Cocoa macOS application.
All tables can try to get data from SQLite data only two tables is showing

```
no such table tablename (code:1)
```

My query for create table is

```
try db.run(table1.create(ifNotExists: true) {t in 
t.column(c1,primaryKey: true)
t.column(c2)
})
try db.run(table2.create(ifNotExists: true) {t in 
t.column(c1,primaryKey: true)
t.column(c2)
})
```

My query to select table count

```
var count = try db.scalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE userid=?",userid) as! Int64
var count = try db.scalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE userid=?",userid) as! Int64
```

although the same code ,it is not working for one table.
Anyone knows how to solve?
Thanks Advance.